# Why is that the top of stack has our input?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering

For context, here is the assembly code and the required knowledge. I will then break down the assembly to see if my understanding is correct.

My main question is: **Why is that the top of stack has our input?**

Here is `main` which calls `phase_2`

```
   0x00000000000014b9 <+112>:   call   0x1200 <puts@plt>
   0x00000000000014be <+117>:   call   0x1c56 <read_line>
   0x00000000000014c3 <+122>:   mov    rdi,rax
   0x00000000000014c6 <+125>:   call   0x15cb <phase_2>
   0x00000000000014cb <+130>:   call   0x1d9e <phase_defused>
```

Here is the `phase_2` which is called from `main`.  The `phase_2` function calls `read_six_numbers`.

```
; phase_2
   0x00000000000015cb <+0>: endbr64 
   0x00000000000015cf <+4>: push   rbp
   0x00000000000015d0 <+5>: push   rbx
   0x00000000000015d1 <+6>: sub    rsp,0x28
   0x00000000000015d5 <+10>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR fs:0x28
   0x00000000000015de <+19>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x18],rax
   0x00000000000015e3 <+24>:    xor    eax,eax
   0x00000000000015e5 <+26>:    mov    rsi,rsp
   0x00000000000015e8 <+29>:    call   0x1c11 <read_six_numbers>
   0x00000000000015ed <+34>:    cmp    DWORD PTR [rsp],0x1
   0x00000000000015f1 <+38>:    jne    0x15fd <phase_2+50>
   0x00000000000015f3 <+40>:    mov    rbx,rsp
   0x00000000000015f6 <+43>:    lea    rbp,[rsp+0x14]
   0x00000000000015fb <+48>:    jmp    0x1612 <phase_2+71>
   0x00000000000015fd <+50>:    call   0x1be5 <explode_bomb>
   0x0000000000001602 <+55>:    jmp    0x15f3 <phase_2+40>
   0x0000000000001604 <+57>:    call   0x1be5 <explode_bomb>
   0x0000000000001609 <+62>:    add    rbx,0x4
   0x000000000000160d <+66>:    cmp    rbx,rbp
   0x0000000000001610 <+69>:    je     0x161d <phase_2+82>
   0x0000000000001612 <+71>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbx]
   0x0000000000001614 <+73>:    add    eax,eax
   0x0000000000001616 <+75>:    cmp    DWORD PTR [rbx+0x4],eax
   0x0000000000001619 <+78>:    je     0x1609 <phase_2+62>
   0x000000000000161b <+80>:    jmp    0x1604 <phase_2+57>
   0x000000000000161d <+82>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x18]
   0x0000000000001622 <+87>:    xor    rax,QWORD PTR fs:0x28
   0x000000000000162b <+96>:    jne    0x1634 <phase_2+105>
   0x000000000000162d <+98>:    add    rsp,0x28
   0x0000000000001631 <+102>:   pop    rbx
   0x0000000000001632 <+103>:   pop    rbp
   0x0000000000001633 <+104>:   ret    
   0x0000000000001634 <+105>:   call   0x1220 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
```

Here is `read_six_numbers` which is called in `phase_2`.

```
; read_six_numbers
   0x0000000000001c11 <+0>: endbr64 
   0x0000000000001c15 <+4>: sub    rsp,0x8
   0x0000000000001c19 <+8>: mov    rdx,rsi
   0x0000000000001c1c <+11>:    lea    rcx,[rsi+0x4]
   0x0000000000001c20 <+15>:    lea    rax,[rsi+0x14]
   0x0000000000001c24 <+19>:    push   rax
   0x0000000000001c25 <+20>:    lea    rax,[rsi+0x10]
   0x0000000000001c29 <+24>:    push   rax
   0x0000000000001c2a <+25>:    lea    r9,[rsi+0xc]
   0x0000000000001c2e <+29>:    lea    r8,[rsi+0x8]
   0x0000000000001c32 <+33>:    lea    rsi,[rip+0x16ca]        # 0x3303
   0x0000000000001c39 <+40>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x0000000000001c3e <+45>:    call   0x12c0 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
   0x0000000000001c43 <+50>:    add    rsp,0x10
   0x0000000000001c47 <+54>:    cmp    eax,0x5
   0x0000000000001c4a <+57>:    jle    0x1c51 <read_six_numbers+64>
   0x0000000000001c4c <+59>:    add    rsp,0x8
   0x0000000000001c50 <+63>:    ret    
   0x0000000000001c51 <+64>:    call   0x1be5 <explode_bomb>
```

Here is my understanding of that is happening in `phase_2`:

```
   0x00000000000015cb <+0>:     endbr64 
   0x00000000000015cf <+4>:     push   rbp
   0x00000000000015d0 <+5>:     push   rbx
   0x00000000000015d1 <+6>:     sub    rsp,0x28
```

Above is the function prologue.
We save the previous base pointer.
We also have the callee saved register `rbx` -- we are pushing to save `rbx`.
Note the pop `rbx` at the end, we restore the value of rbx because we overwrite `rbx` in the function.
`rbx` is a system V callee saved register
If the callee wishes to use registers `RBX`, `RSP`, `RBP`, and `R12`–`R15`, it must restore their original values before returning control to the caller.

```
   0x00000000000015d5 <+10>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR fs:0x28
```

The above is a stack canary. If modified, the program ends

```
   0x00000000000015de <+19>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x18],rax
```

We move the return value and put it in a local var.
The previous value is the return value of read_line.

```
   0x00000000000015e3 <+24>:    xor    eax,eax
```

We then clear `eax`.
we clear `rax` because clearing the values also cancels out the top values of `rax`.

```
   0x00000000000015e5 <+26>:    mov    rsi,rsp
```

**Why are moving the address at the top of the stack, i.e., `rsp` and placing it into `rsi`?
I'm guessing the top of stack is the beginning of our 6 digits, but
how did our 6 digits get to begin at the of the stack?**

```
   0x00000000000015ed <+34>:    cmp    DWORD PTR [rsp],0x1
```

We verify that the value where `rsp` points is `0x1`.

```
   0x00000000000015f1 <+38>:    jne    0x15fd <phase_2+50>
```

If not, we end the function.

```
   0x00000000000015f3 <+40>:    mov    rbx,rsp
```

We move the contents of `rsp`, the address of the top of the stack, into `rbx`.

**Is there any reason for this?**

```
   0x00000000000015f6 <+43>:    lea    rbp,[rsp+0x14]
```

We move a local variable into `rbp`.

**Why is this done? This local variable was never initialized? Are me moving a random variable into `rbp` and why `rbp`?**

Is it related to when we moved `rsp + 0x18`.
It is 4 bytes larger, so are we accessing an array + 1?

```
   0x0000000000001609 <+62>:    add    rbx,0x4
```

Beginning of the loop.
We increment the array/string by one integer.

```
   0x0000000000001612 <+71>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbx
```

Earlier we moved the top of the stack into `rbx`.
We dereference what was pointed.
We now put that into `eax`.

```
   0x0000000000001614 <+73>:    add    eax,eax
```

We double what is in eax

```
   0x0000000000001616 <+75>:    cmp    DWORD PTR [rbx+0x4],eax
   0x0000000000001619 <+78>:    je     0x1609 <phase_2+62>
```

**Why are we comparing the what I assume to be `array[i + 1]` and not just `array[i]`?**
**What *is* `rbx` and why does it it hold the value we are comparing out input to?**

And the rest is function epilogue and the checking the stack canary.

Comment: Because that's where the caller asked `read_six_numbers` to put the results.  Note the `mov    rsi,rsp`  / `call read_six_numbers` to copy RSP to the 2nd arg-padding register.  (With RDI still holding the incoming function arg to `phase_2`, which is the string that holds the input line.)  I assume `read_six_numbers` is going to call `sscanf(rdi, "%d %d %d %d %d %d", rsi, rsi+4, rsi+8, ...)`

Comment: @PeterCordes So the `lea    rsi,[rip+0x16ca] ` is putting the string data into arguments for `sscanf()`? I thought the order was `RDI`,  `RSI`, and so forth and then you push the arguments that don't fit into the register? What's with the weird arguments? Or would this be better suited for a new question?

Comment: No, the RIP-relative LEA is the format string, the 2nd arg to `sscanf`.  The `rdi` and `rsi` in my pseudocode call to sscanf were incoming args to `read_six_numbers`, not the registers they're in when it calls sscanf.  Note the `mov rdx,rsi` and `lea rcx, [rsi+4]` and so on to create those `rsi`, `rsi+4`, etc. pointer args in `read_six_numbers`.